# cscript jscript JSON

Tags: json, asp-classic, jscript, wsh

This is a very very (very!!!) strange problem.

I have this JSCRIPT that runs on windows XP and 7 using dos `CSCRIPT` in a file called `testJSON.js`.

```
if ( ! this.JSON ) WScript.Echo("JSON DOESN'T EXISTS");
```

And, well, the message appear, but is an unexpected behavior of JSCRIPT because JSON (as the [**MSDN** documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836458%28v=vs.84%29.aspx) says) is one of the default object in the `JSCRIPT 5.8` and my system on Windows 7 runs exactly `JSCRIPT 5.8`.

Now, I have temporary solved this problem (in a little complex script) by creating a new text file and MANUALLY composing a valid JSON string (and, obviously this makes everything works fine even if the system doesn't have the `JSCRIPT 5.8` as requested for JSON) but I like to know two things mainly:

**1st** Why I can't use the JSON object even if my JSCRIPT version is the one that supports that object?

**2nd** I have [read something about the "enabling" of the JSON (and other) unavailable object](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512774%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in my JSCRIPT environment, but all examples is for C# and I like to know if some equivalent code for JSCRIPT exists or not.

Comment: While this is not a question about Classic ASP, it contains information which is really useful if you're using Classic ASP with jscript as your server side language - hence I added the tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Why I can't use the JSON object even if my JSCRIPT version is the one that supports that object?

According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836458(v=vs.84).aspx), Windows Script Host uses the JScript 5.7 feature set by default for backward compatibility. The JScript 5.8 feature set is only used in Internet Explorer in the IE8+ Standards document modes.

You have the following options:

1. Include [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) in your script. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/928237/113116) for options for including external scripts in JScript scripts.
2. <s>Modify the registry to [expose IE9's JScript engine to Windows Script Host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7167690/what-is-the-progid-or-clsid-for-ie9s-javascript-engine-code-named-chakra).</s> UPD: This solution uses IE's JScript DLLs, but doesn't activate the 5.8 feature set.
3. [Create a JScript execution host programmatically](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fdee6589(v=vs.94).aspx) using the Active Script interfaces and use [`IActiveScriptProperty::SetProperty`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc512774(v=vs.94).aspx) to force the JScript 5.8 feature set (`SCRIPTLANGUAGEVERSION_5_8`). [Here's a C++ example](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jscript/archive/2009/04/17/versioning-language-features-in-jscript.aspx#10166730).

> I have read something about the "enabling" of the JSON (and other) unavailable object in my JSCRIPT environment, but all examples is for C# and I like to know if some equivalent code for JSCRIPT exists or not.

Custom script execution hosts can be created only using languages with proper COM support, such as C++, C# etc. JScript can't be used for that, because, for example, it doesn't support out parameters.

Comment: Unfortunate, but true.  Why there is no override or param on wscript/script is beyond me.

Comment: Wow, that `WSH` is a total joke. Thanks, Microsoft!

Comment: @rojo: You should add this as an answer.

Comment: @Helen Not sure whether you care, but I found a hacksy workaround that I thought was pretty clever.  See my edited answer below.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out json2.js; what I did was create a little .wsf file that included that javascript file and then included my own script file.  Worked great!

Comment: If you're still reading this, thanks for the suggestion.  I turned json2.js into a Classic asp include file by adding `<%` at the start and `%>` at the end.

Answer (score 20):

You can use `eval()` to achieve an effect similar to `JSON.parse()`.

```
eval('obj = {' + JSONstring + '}');
```

And afterwards, `obj.toString()` will let you retrieve the data similar to `JSON.stringify()` (just without the beautify options). [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27631421/1683264) for an example in the wild. The point is, you can create an object from JSON text without having to load any external libraries or switch the interpreter engine.

### BIG FAT WARNING!!!

This introduces a vulnerability into the workstation running your code.  If you do not control the generation of the JSON you wish to parse, or if it is possible that a 3rd party might modify the JSON between its generation and its interpretation, then consider following [Helen's advice](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19488752/1683264).  If bad things are in the JSON, it can cause your WScript to do bad things.  For example, if your JSON string or file contains the following:

```
};
var oSH = WSH.CreateObject("wscript.shell"),
    cmd = oSH.Exec("%comspec%");
WSH.Sleep(250);
cmd.StdIn.WriteLine("net user pwnd password /add");
WSH.Sleep(250);
cmd.StdIn.WriteLine("net group Administrators pwnd /add");
WSH.Sleep(250);
cmd.Terminate();
var obj = {
    "objName": {
        "item1": "value 1",
        "item2": "value 2"
    }
```

... then parsing it with `eval` will have just added a new administrator to your computer without any visual indication that it happened.

My advice is to feel free to employ `eval` for private or casual use; but for widespread deployment, consider including [json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) as Helen suggests.  **Edit:** Or...

#### htmlfile COM object

You can import the JSON methods by invoking the `htmlfile` COM object and forcing it into IE9 (or higher) compatibility mode by means of a `<META>` tag like this:

```
var htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'), JSON;
htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');
htmlfile.close(JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON);
```

With those three lines, the JSON object and methods are copied into the JScript runtime, letting you parse JSON without using `eval()` or downloading json2.js.  You can now do stuff like this:

```
var pretty = JSON.stringify(JSON.parse(json), null, '\t');
WSH.Echo(pretty);
```

Here's a breakdown:

```
// load htmlfile COM object and declare empty JSON object
var htmlfile = WSH.CreateObject('htmlfile'), JSON;

// force htmlfile to load Chakra engine
htmlfile.write('<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=9" />');

// The following statement is an overloaded compound statement, a code golfing trick.
// The "JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON" statement is executed first, copying the
// htmlfile COM object's JSON object and methods into "JSON" declared above; then
// "htmlfile.close()" ignores its argument and unloads the now unneeded COM object.
htmlfile.close(JSON = htmlfile.parentWindow.JSON);
```

[See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33808191/1683264) for other methods (json2.js download via XHR, `InternetExplorer.Application` COM object, an HTA hybrid method, and another example of `htmlfile`).

Comment: Why did you have to assign JSON in the parameter area? What's wrong with doing that one line above closing?

Comment: I didn't have to.  It's just a code golfing trick, stuffing a command as an overloaded argument into a method that expects no arguments.  3 lines of code looks more impressive than 4.  It's completely a matter of personal preference.  [See this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34966337/1683264) for a demonstration of importing other Chakra methods into JScript.

Answer (score 1):

JSON encode, decode without default parser: https://gist.github.com/gnh1201/e372f5de2e076dbee205a07eb4064d8d

```
var $ = {};

/**
 * Decode JSON
 *
 * @param string jsonString - JSON text
 *
 * @return object
 */
$.json.decode = function(jsonString) {
    return (new Function("return " + jsonString)());
};

/**
 * Encode JSON
 *
 * @param object obj - Key/Value object
 *
 * @return string
 */
$.json.encode = function(obj) {
    var items = [];
    var isArray = (function(_obj) {
        try {
            return (_obj instanceof Array);
        } catch (e) {
            return false;
        }
    })(obj);
    var _toString = function(_obj) {
        try {
            if(typeof(_obj) == "object") {
                return $.json.encode(_obj);
            } else {
                var s = String(_obj).replace(/"/g, '\\"');
                if(typeof(_obj) == "number" || typeof(_obj) == "boolean") {
                    return s;
                } else {
                    return '"' + s + '"';
                }
            }
        } catch (e) {
            return "null";
        }
    };

    for(var k in obj) {
        var v = obj[k];

        if(!isArray) {
            items.push('"' + k + '":' + _toString(v));
        } else {
            items.push(_toString(v));
        }
    }

    if(!isArray) {
        return "{" + items.join(",") + "}";
    } else {
        return "[" + items.join(",") + "]";
    }
};

/**
 * Test JSON
 *
 * @param object obj - Key/Value object
 *
 * @return boolean
 */
$.json.test = function(obj) {
    var t1 = obj;
    var t2 = $.json.encode(obj);
    $.echo($.json.encode(t1));

    var t3 = $.json.decode(t2);
    var t4 = $.json.encode(t3);
    $.echo(t4);

    if(t2 == t4) {
        $.echo("success");
        return true;
    } else {
        $.echo("failed");
        return false;
    }
};

/**
 * Echo
 *
 * @param string txt
 *
 * @return void
 */
$.echo = function(txt) {
    if($.isWScript()) {
        WScript.Echo(txt);
    } else {
        try {
            window.alert(txt);
        } catch (e) {
            console.log(txt);
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Check if WScript
 *
 * @return bool
 */
$.isWScript = function() {
    return typeof(WScript) !== "undefined";
}

// test your data
var t1 = {"a": 1, "b": "banana", "c": {"d": 2, "e": 3}, "f": [100, 200, "3 hundreds", {"g": 4}]};
$.json.test(t1);
```