# Get json config value into windows script variable

Tags: json, windows, batch-file, cmd, jq

I would like to parse config.json file and gets some specific values into variables.

Following command is working, it print value from json:
`type config.json | "jq-win64.exe" .path.editor`

- config.json content:
  `{ "path" : { "editor" : "...value..." } }`
- jq is library for json (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/)

Question is how to get this value into some variable ?

I tried this, but is not working:
`set editorPath = type config.json | "jq-win64.exe" -r .path.editor`

Result is that `%editorPath%` is empty

Maybe it's related to jq library (https://stedolan.github.io/jq/) but I am quite noob in windows shell so maybe someone can help how to solve this issue.

Thanks

Comment: You might find [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31701650/1683264) useful.  Since your JSON is formatted properly, remove the braces from the `eval` line, and `echo editor: !editor!`

Comment: In general, when you want to capture the output of a command to a variable, use a `for /F` loop.  `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('command') do set "variable=%%I"` or similar.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, when you want to capture the output of a command to a variable, use a `for /F` loop.  `for /f "delims=" %%I in ('command') do set "variable=%%I"` or similar.  See `help for` in a cmd console for more info.

---

It is possible to make JScript interpret JSON similar to the way JavaScript would.  There are [security concerns](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27643386/1683264); but if you can be reasonably certain no one is likely to insert malicious code into the JSON, you can parse it without requiring 3rd party tools.

---

This example script combines the two ideas mentioned above -- invoking a JScript code block with `cscript.exe`, and capturing its output with a `for /f` loop.

**config.json:**

```js
{ "path" : { "editor" : "...value..." } }
```

**parseJSON.bat:**

```js
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then

@echo off
setlocal

set "JSONfile=config.json"

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('cscript /nologo /e:JScript "%~f0" "%JSONfile%"') do set "%%~I"

rem // Delayed expansion prevents path names with symbols (& or %) from choking the script
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
echo editor: !editor!
endlocal

goto :EOF

@end // end batch / begin JScript chimera

var fso = WSH.CreateObject('scripting.filesystemobject'),
    JSONfile = fso.OpenTextFile(WSH.Arguments(0), 1);

eval('obj = ' + JSONfile.ReadAll());
JSONfile.Close();

function walk(tree) {
    for (var i in tree) {
        if (typeof tree[i] === 'object') walk(tree[i]);
        else WSH.Echo(i + '=' + tree[i]);
    }
}

walk(obj);
```

**Output:**

> editor: ...value...

Comment: Thanks this helped me to quite understand issue..

Now I have something like: 

``for /f "delims=" %%I in ('readConfig .path.to.something') do set PathToSomething=%%I`` 

and it seem to be doing what I needed.


readConfig is only doing output of jq commands...

Answer (score 0):

Here are illustrations of two approaches using jq:

```
@echo off
setlocal

for /f "delims=" %%I in ('jq -n -r "\"123\""') do set A=%%I
echo A is %A%

jq -n -r  "@sh \"set B=123\"" > setvars.bat
call .\setvars.bat
echo B is %B%
```

In the first example, the batch file determines the variable name; in the second example, the jq program determines the variable name(s).

By the way, for non-Windows users, there is a "recipe" about this in the [jq Cookbook](https://github.com/stedolan/jq/wiki/Cookbook#extract-data-and-set-shell-variables).

Answer (score 0):

This is very easy for [Xidel](http://videlibri.sourceforge.net/xidel.html).

Dot notation:

```
xidel -s config.json -e "($json).path.editor"
```

XPath notation:

```
xidel -s config.json -e "$json/path/editor"

or even shorter

xidel -s config.json -e "$json//editor"
```

Export value to "editorPath" variable:

```
FOR /F "delims=" %A IN ('xidel -s config.json -e "editorPath:=$json//editor" --output-format^=cmd') DO %A
```