# vbscript output to console

Tags: windows, vbscript, console, output

What is the command or the quickest way to output results to console using vbscript?

Answer (score 364, accepted):

You mean:

```
WScript.Echo "Like this?"
```

If you run that under `wscript.exe` (the default handler for the .vbs extension, so what you'll get if you double-click the script) you'll get a "MessageBox" dialog with your text in it. If you run that under `cscript.exe` you'll get output in your console window.

Comment: You can directly use on the wscript.exe the function `MsgBox("text")` or `MsgBox(object.property)` but `Wscript.Echo` is easier to write. Thanks.

Comment: Unintuitively for me, `WScript.Echo` *must* be used for whether you're running via `WScript` or `CScript`. That is, there *is not* a `CScript.Echo`, in case future googlers wonder. (*Very* happy the msgboxes are gone [when run with `cscript`], however; thanks.)

Comment: @GabrielStaples - Not w/ the stock `WScript.Echo`. I suppose, if you wanted to stay totally within WScript you could do something horrifyingly dodgy like Exec'ing off another process to do a "SendKeys" to the parent process to close the MessageBox.

Comment: Actually, I just found this `popup` method. Very similar to `echo` but allows you to specify a timeout after which it will automatically close the popup box. Very convenient and easy to use: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156593.aspx

Answer (score 74):

This was found on [*Dragon-IT Scripts and Code Repository*](http://scripts.dragon-it.co.uk/links/vbscript-writing-to-stdout-stderr?OpenDocument).

You can do this with the following and stay away from the cscript/wscript differences and allows you to get the same console output that a batch file would have.  This can help if your calling VBS from a batch file and need to make it look seamless.

```
Set fso = CreateObject ("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set stdout = fso.GetStandardStream (1)
Set stderr = fso.GetStandardStream (2)
stdout.WriteLine "This will go to standard output."
stderr.WriteLine "This will go to error output."
```

Comment: If the script is started by double-click and thus opened with wscript, the script results in an error message: "Invalid Handle".

Comment: @Bernhard: You are getting this error if you run the script using wscript.exe. Wscript is windows-oriented and has no console streams. Use cscript.exe instead: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490816.aspx

Comment: @BernhardHiller has a valid point. The thrust of this answer is that using stdout directly would avoid the CScript/WScript differences. That is incorrect. This solution still only works under CScript.exe, so there doesn't seem to be much benefit over just using `WScript.Echo`. In fact, the difference is magnified, because the script will no longer run at all under WScript. Its a valid technique that has its uses, for example if one needs to write to StdErr, but in the context of this answer, it is misleading.

Comment: I just want to light up the benefit of this method over `WScript.Echo`:

`cscript //b foobar.vbs`

Runs `foobar.vbs` without any console output, but by Rob's method you can have output even when passing `\\b` to `cscript.exe`

Answer (score 31):

You only need to force cscript instead wscript. I always use this template. The function ForceConsole() will execute your vbs into cscript, also you have nice alias to print and scan text.

```
 Set oWSH = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
 vbsInterpreter = "cscript.exe"

 Call ForceConsole()

 Function printf(txt)
    WScript.StdOut.WriteLine txt
 End Function

 Function printl(txt)
    WScript.StdOut.Write txt
 End Function

 Function scanf()
    scanf = LCase(WScript.StdIn.ReadLine)
 End Function

 Function wait(n)
    WScript.Sleep Int(n * 1000)
 End Function

 Function ForceConsole()
    If InStr(LCase(WScript.FullName), vbsInterpreter) = 0 Then
        oWSH.Run vbsInterpreter & " //NoLogo " & Chr(34) & WScript.ScriptFullName & Chr(34)
        WScript.Quit
    End If
 End Function

 Function cls()
    For i = 1 To 50
        printf ""
    Next
 End Function

 printf " _____ _ _           _____         _    _____         _     _   "
 printf "|  _  |_| |_ ___ ___|     |_ _ _ _| |  |   __|___ ___|_|___| |_ "
 printf "|     | | '_| . |   |   --| | | | . |  |__   |  _|  _| | . |  _|"
 printf "|__|__|_|_,_|___|_|_|_____|_____|___|  |_____|___|_| |_|  _|_|  "
 printf "                                                       |_|     v1.0"
 printl " Enter your name:"
 MyVar = scanf
 cls
 printf "Your name is: " & MyVar
 wait(5)
```

Comment: Are you sure that answers the [actual question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388879/vbscript-output-to-console)?

Comment: Yes, only call the ForceConsole() and then use printf() to print text in the output console. Also you have other alias to clear screen, scan text and wait (sleep)

Comment: Best solution ever, thank you, but only the "ForceConsole" function matters, the "printf" and the rest are totally unnecessary since if you force to close the current script on Wscript.exe instance and then run a new cscript.exe instance of the current script, then Wscript.Echo will output to that console instance...

Answer (score 10):

There are five ways to output text to the console:

```
Dim StdOut : Set StdOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetStandardStream(1)

WScript.Echo "Hello"
WScript.StdOut.Write "Hello"
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Hello"
Stdout.WriteLine "Hello"
Stdout.Write "Hello"
```

WScript.Echo will output to console but only if the script is started using cscript.exe. It will output to message boxes if started using wscript.exe.

WScript.StdOut.Write and WScript.StdOut.WriteLine will always output to console.

StdOut.Write and StdOut.WriteLine will also always output to console. It requires extra object creation but it is about 10% faster than WScript.Echo.

Comment: ... and as said in a comment to a previous answers, this doesn't work when executing with wscript.exe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388879/vbscript-output-to-console#comment26762213_12865458

Comment: Also found an explanation about GetStandardStream() vs WScript.StdIn/.StdOut/.StdErr : "VBScript in a Nutshell: A Desktop Quick Reference (2nd Edition)" https://books.google.fr/books?id=NLpuZSatG3QC page 298 says it's "functionnaly equivalent".

Comment: When you say "this doesn't work", can you specify which of the five method does not work and what you mean by not working?

Answer (score 6):

I came across this post and went back to an approach that I used some time ago which is similar to @MadAntrax's.

The main difference is that it uses a VBScript user-defined class to wrap all the logic for switching to CScript and outputting text to the console, so it makes the main script a bit cleaner.

This assumes that your objective is to stream output to the console, rather than having output go to message boxes.

The cCONSOLE class is below. To use it, include the complete class at the end of your script, and then instantiate it right at the beginning of the script. Here is an example:

```
    Option Explicit

'// Instantiate the console object, this automatically switches to CSCript if required
Dim CONS: Set CONS = New cCONSOLE

'// Now we can use the Consol object to write to and read from the console
With CONS

    '// Simply write a line
     .print "CSCRIPT Console demo script"

     '// Arguments are passed through correctly, if present
     .Print "Arg count=" & wscript.arguments.count

     '// List all the arguments on the console log
     dim ix
     for ix = 0 to wscript.arguments.count -1
        .print "Arg(" & ix & ")=" & wscript.arguments(ix)
     next

     '// Prompt for some text from the user
     dim sMsg : sMsg = .prompt( "Enter any text:" )

     '// Write out the text in a box
     .Box sMsg

     '// Pause with the message "Hit enter to continue"
     .Pause

End With     




'= =========== End of script - the cCONSOLE class code follows here
```

Here is the code for the cCONSOLE class

```
     CLASS cCONSOLE
 '= =================================================================
 '= 
 '=    This class provides automatic switch to CScript and has methods
 '=    to write to and read from the CSCript console. It transparently
 '=    switches to CScript if the script has been started in WScript.
 '=
 '= =================================================================

    Private oOUT
    Private oIN


    Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    '= Run on creation of the cCONSOLE object, checks for cScript operation


        '= Check to make sure we are running under CScript, if not restart
        '= then run using CScript and terminate this instance.
        dim oShell
        set oShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

        If InStr( LCase( WScript.FullName ), "cscript.exe" ) = 0 Then
            '= Not running under CSCRIPT

            '= Get the arguments on the command line and build an argument list
            dim ArgList, IX
            ArgList = ""

            For IX = 0 to wscript.arguments.count - 1
                '= Add the argument to the list, enclosing it in quotes
                argList = argList & " """ & wscript.arguments.item(IX) & """"
            next

            '= Now restart with CScript and terminate this instance
            oShell.Run "cscript.exe //NoLogo """ & WScript.ScriptName & """ " & arglist
            WScript.Quit

        End If

        '= Running under CScript so OK to continue
        set oShell = Nothing

        '= Save references to stdout and stdin for use with Print, Read and Prompt
        set oOUT = WScript.StdOut
        set oIN = WScript.StdIn

        '= Print out the startup box 
            StartBox
            BoxLine Wscript.ScriptName
            BoxLine "Started at " & Now()
            EndBox


    End Sub

    '= Utility methods for writing a box to the console with text in it

            Public Sub StartBox()

                Print "  " & String(73, "_") 
                Print " |" & Space(73) & "|"
            End Sub

            Public Sub BoxLine(sText)

                Print Left(" |" & Centre( sText, 74) , 75) & "|"
            End Sub

            Public Sub EndBox()
                Print " |" & String(73, "_") & "|"
                Print ""
            End Sub

            Public Sub Box(sMsg)
                StartBox
                BoxLine sMsg
                EndBox
            End Sub

    '= END OF Box utility methods


            '= Utility to center given text padded out to a certain width of text
            '= assuming font is monospaced
            Public Function Centre(sText, nWidth)
                dim iLen
                iLen = len(sText)

                '= Check for overflow
                if ilen > nwidth then Centre = sText : exit Function

                '= Calculate padding either side
                iLen = ( nWidth - iLen ) / 2

                '= Generate text with padding
                Centre = left( space(iLen) & sText & space(ilen), nWidth )
            End Function



    '= Method to write a line of text to the console
    Public Sub Print( sText )

        oOUT.WriteLine sText
    End Sub

    '= Method to prompt user input from the console with a message
    Public Function Prompt( sText )
        oOUT.Write sText
        Prompt = Read()
    End Function

    '= Method to read input from the console with no prompting
    Public Function Read()
        Read = oIN.ReadLine
    End Function

    '= Method to provide wait for n seconds
    Public Sub Wait(nSeconds)
        WScript.Sleep  nSeconds * 1000 
    End Sub

    '= Method to pause for user to continue
    Public Sub Pause
        Prompt "Hit enter to continue..."
    End Sub


 END CLASS
```

Comment: "_include the complete class at the end of your script_" isn't necessary when using a [WSF](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/c999e0fa-3986-41be-90a9-3f8ae3a38253.asp). See also [Etalon's answer to _How do I include a common file in VBScript (similar to C #include)?_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12374208/1744774)

Answer (score 1):

Create a .vbs with the following code, which will open your main .vbs:

```
Set objShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.shell") 
objShell.Run "cscript.exe ""C:\QuickTestb.vbs"""
```

Here is my main .vbs

```
Option Explicit
Dim i
for i = 1 To 5
     Wscript.Echo i
     Wscript.Sleep 5000
Next
```

Comment: Isn't `Sleep` a bit counter-intuitive if OP asks for the *quickest way*?

Comment: @Wolf Perhaps OP meant _quickest to write_. OK, agreed, not even that applies. :)

Answer (score 0):

You can run this script to echo in the command line

```
set wshShell = createObject("wscript.shell")
    wshShell.run"cmd.exe /c echo something",1
```

Answer (score 0):

For console output I use a snippet that quits elegantly if run in the wrong run-time. (And print is shorter to type...)

```
Sub print(s) 
  On Error Resume Next
  WScript.stdout.WriteLine (s)  
  If  err= &h80070006& Then WScript.Echo " Please run this script with CScript": WScript.quit
End Sub
 
print "hello"
```