# How to run VBS function with parameters from Java and assign result to variable

Tags: java, excel, vbscript, vba

I have this excel macro:

```
Function Calculate_Something(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date) As Double

//some math is here, not important

Calculate_Something = Result
End Function
```

And I want to pass my dates to this macro, execute it in my Java program and finally get returned value and assign it to my value in Java.

I have created VBS script with this function and try to execute it like this in Java:

```
 String[] parms = {"wscript", "calc.vbs", "2017-02-06 09:38:36", "2017-02-06 12:47:41"};
 Runtime.getRuntime().exec(parms);
```

But it didn't work. Do you know how could I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will want to use `cscript.exe` instead of `wscript.exe`, they are both the same host but one is designed for GUI while the other is designed for the command line.

Modify the VBScript function to [output the `Result` to screen](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4388879/692942) *(the executed command output stream)* then retrieve it using the `Process` object derived from calling `Runtime.getRuntime().exec(parms);`.

There is a method of the `Process` object called `getInputStream()` which should allow you to access and read the value you returned by the script output.

```java
try {
    String[] parms = {"cscript", "calc.vbs", "2017-02-06 09:38:36", "2017-02-06 12:47:41"};
    Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(parms);

    // Get Input Stream from the Process
    BufferedReader is = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));

    // Do something with stream, read etc.
    String line;
    while ((line = is.readLine()) != null)
        System.out.println(line);

} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

---

#### Useful Links

- [vbscript output to console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4388879/692942)
- [What is InputStream & Output Stream? Why do we use them and when do we use each of them?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1830698/692942)
- [Understanding getInputStream and getOutputStream](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22563986/692942)