# Vbs print to console

Tags: vbscript

Can i somehow print texe in .vbs file to cmd console?
I tried that:

```
Dim StdOut : Set StdOut = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetStandardStream(1)
    
WScript.Echo "Hello"
WScript.StdOut.Write "Hello"
WScript.StdOut.WriteLine "Hello"
Stdout.WriteLine "Hello"
Stdout.Write "Hello"
```

It show an error when i run it with cmd also without.
[see_an_error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HiDos.png)
Can somebody help me?
Thanks for answare.

Comment: [The StdIn, StdOut, and StdErr streams can be accessed while using CScript.exe only. Attempting to access these streams while using WScript.exe produces an error.](https://www.vbsedit.com/html/cb7c65bf-2dce-40ab-b769-3fd59941f74b.asp)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388879/vbscript-output-to-console

Comment: Does this answer your question? [vbscript output to console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4388879/vbscript-output-to-console)

Comment: Helo @Moir. No when i tried "Wscript.Echo "Like this?"" it show only pop up message but i wanna to write it to the console.

Comment: @Filip I believe you read the question rather then the answers.

Comment: @Moir i tried and it work but it can only write to cscript.exe. I want write to console.