# Retrieving an argument of a VBScript

Tags: vbscript, arguments

How do I pass and return arguments from a VBScript WITHOUT using `cscript.exe`?

For example, I want to call script2 from script1 that returns a value to script1 without any involvement of `cscript.exe`.
I have searched various answers but they somehow involve the usage of `cscript.exe`.

This script gets installed voices and sets the one provided in the file `voice.txt`.

```
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
WShShell.CurrentDirectory = "..\Confirmatory Texts"

Set FSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If FSO.FileExists("voice.txt") Then
  Set temp = FSO.OpenTextFile("voice.txt")
  confirm_voice = temp.ReadLine()
  temp.Close

  Set Sapi = CreateObject("SAPI.SpVoice")

  For Each Voice In Sapi.GetVoices
    i = i + 1
  Next

  For loopvar = 0 To i-1
    If loopvar = CInt(confirm_voice) Then
      Set Sapi.Voice = Sapi.GetVoices.Item(loopvar)
    End If
  Next
Else
  WScript.Echo "An Error Occured"
End If
```

If I call this script from another script, how can I make this script to return some value to the script that invoked it?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and provide a [mcve] of _both_ scripts. As currently written, your question seems to be a bit unclear what is `script2`,  what is `script1`, how they call each other etc… Why not to use `wscript.exe` instead of `cscript.exe`? BTW, `Sapi.GetVoices.Item(loopvar)` is an **object** `ISpeechObjectToken`; you can't manipulate it as a string…

Comment: VBScript help file is here https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=2764. See *Script Components*. Another way is to use 32 bit CScript and load the Script Control, load your second script into the script control and execute it. My answer here shows that - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26952155/how-to-make-an-include-activex-object-in-vb6-for-vbscript.

Comment: i want this above script to return some value to the script which invoked it ,  how can i do that ? and BTW thanks for replying guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

VBScript doesn't really provide call or import mechanisms for other VBScript files. The closest thing is to read the contents of the other file and run them via [`ExecuteGlobal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/342311f1%28v=vs.84%29).

**Demonstration:**

Put the following two files in the same directory and run `script1.vbs`. It will read the contents of `script2.vbs` and make the function `Square` available in the global scope by running the code via `ExecuteGlobal`. Once the function is available in the global scope you it can be used in the rest of the script.

`script1.vbs`:

```
Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

dir    = fso.GetParentFolderName(WScript.ScriptFullName)
script = fso.BuildPath(dir, "script2.vbs")

ExecuteGlobal fso.OpenTextFile(script).ReadAll  '"import" code into global scope

WScript.Echo Square(3)
```

`script2.vbs`:

```
Function Square(i)
  Square = i*i
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer , i will try that approach .

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all scripts into header scripts and import them through this code:

```vb
' Features:
'   * Builtin of inclusion guard
'   * Inclusion path can be relative to the script directory
Class ImportFunction
    Private imports_dict_obj_
    Private fs_obj_

    Private Sub CLASS_INITIALIZE
        set imports_dict_obj_ = WScript.createObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
        set fs_obj_ = WScript.createObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    End Sub

    Public Default Property Get func(file_path_str)
        If "/" = Left(file_path_str, 1) Then
            ' is relative to the script directory
            script_file_path_str = WScript.ScriptFullName
            Dim script_file_obj : Set script_file_obj = fs_obj_.GetFile(script_file_path_str)
            file_path_str = fs_obj_.GetParentFolderName(script_file_obj) & file_path_str
        End If
        file_path_str = fs_obj_.GetAbsolutePathName(file_path_str)

        If Not imports_dict_obj_.Exists(file_path_str) Then
            ExecuteGlobal fs_obj_.OpenTextFile(file_path_str).ReadAll()
            imports_dict_obj_.Add file_path_str, Null
        End If
    End Property
End Class

Dim Import : Set Import = New ImportFunction

Import("/mylib.vbs")

MyLibFoo
```

**Pros**:

- A global dictionary used as a storage for inclusion guards.
- You can import a script with relative path to itself using leading slash in the path.

**Cons**:

- Windows 10+ can treat the `ExecuteGlobal` call as a malware activity and block it. Then you will have to explicitly allow each script containing the `ExecuteGlobal` call.