# including classes with a wsc file

Tags: vbscript, com, include, createobject, wsc

Ok, what am i doing wrong here? 
i'm trying to include a vbscript with a class inside this way:

**SCRIPT.VBS:**

```
set inc = createobject("script.runner")
inc.Include "class"
set x = new test
x.msg' here i get the error 'undefined class'!
```

**REGISTERED .wsc file:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<component>
<registration
description="wsc"
progid="script.runner"
version="1.00"
classid="{f65e154c-43b3-4f8f-aa3d-535af68f51d1}"
>
</registration>
<public>
<method name="Include">
<PARAMETER name="Script"/>
</method>
</public>
<script language="VBScript">
<![CDATA[
Sub Include(Script)
ExecuteGlobal(CreateObject("scripting.filesystemobject").OpenTextFile(Script & ".vbs", 1).Readall & VBNewLine)
End Sub
]]>
</script>
</component>
```

**CLASS.VBS:**

```
class test
public sub msg
msgbox "hi"
end sub
end class
```

I was thinking maybe i need to define it in the wsc file if i'm going to use classes or something? 
i don't know..

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

VBscript's Execute(Global) and .COM are very different ways of re-using code. You shouldn't mix them.

A .wsc lets you create one object and use its methods and properties. Such a method (factory) may create and return another object. So if you add

```
<method name="mkTest">
</method>
...
Function mkTest()
  Set mkTest = New test
End Function
```

to your .wsc and

```
set x = inc.mkTest
x.msg
```

to your .vbs, the whole rigmarole will 'work'.

You should think about your real world task, read a [good book about .COM](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201634465), and come up with a **simple** strategy that does not mix heterogeneous technologies (maybe the Sub Include()/ExecuteGlobal approach sketched [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26951329/603855)).

Answer (score 0):

did this:

**script**

```
set inc = createobject("script.runner")
inc.Include "C:\Users\GEEK\Desktop\small"
set x = inc.AddClass("test")
x.msg' here i get the error 'undefined class'!
```

**inside wsc method**

```
Function AddClass(ClassName)
execute("Set AddClass = New " & ClassName)
end Function
```

and Ekkehard.Horner,
You're right.
I'm just to curious about how to solve a problem even when there are easier ways to do
something ^^

Thanks for all the help!

regards