# Load library written by user

Tags: vbscript

I have written a library in VBScript.

Now I would like to use it in another VBScript, but am not sure of the syntax.

How do I load my library given that its path is:

`C://User/My Documents/VBlib.vbs`

Normaly to load a class from an external library I would do:

`Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")`

To my understanding one of the possible solutions is to add my library to
[object reference library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264402.aspx) but by library has wrong file extension for that.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/q/27069802/603855 for a .wsc (=OO) approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tend to use `ExecuteGlobal` as a way of including function libraries I've written to other `vbs` files.  I wrap it in a function called `IncludeFile` like this and add the function to the bottom of my vbscript, then use it to 'add' my function libraries:

```
IncludeFile "\\path\to\my\library.vbs"

'... vbscript here can call any functions belonging to the library


' so long as this function is in the script at the end, anyway
Function IncludeFile(ByVal oFunctionLib)
    Dim oFso : Set oFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Dim oLibrary : Set oLibrary = oFso.OpenTextFile(oFunctionLib, 1, False)
    Dim sFunctions : sFunctions = oLibrary.ReadAll
    oLibrary.Close
    Set oLibrary = Nothing
    Set oFso = Nothing
    ExecuteGlobal sFunctions
End Function
```

Comment: `ExecuteGlobal` never heard of it but it works like a charm.